# Yii2 gridview - unwanted page reload after ajax request

Tags: php, yii, yii2, pjax

I'm using GridView widget with jquery Pjax for displaying data in my Yii2 application. I need to have ajax sort and filter in my grid, so I have put my grid configuration between these lines of codes:

```
 Pjax::begin([
    'timeout' => 10000,
    'id' => 'products-container',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'type' => "POST",
    ],
]);
?>  

<?=
GridView::widget([
   //grid configuration
])
?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

When I want to sort the grid with a column or use grid filter, I see the browser sends an ajax request to server, but after finishing ajax, the entire page reload!

Or, even when I execute this code in the browser console, after sending ajax request, the page reloads.

```
$.pjax.reload("#products-container", {
    "type": "POST"
});
```

What is the problem?

**Update:**

I found that the problem is upgrading server's php version to 7! I downgrade version to 5.6 and problem fixed. But the main server must have latest version, so I must use php 7. **What is the problem with pjax and php 7?**
My yii version is 2.0.8

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same problem and I'm suspecting PHP 7 is the issue (I also have no option of downgrading). I can see the "loading" icon showing up and trying to get the PJAX data but then the whole page reloads. No solution is available yet?

Answer (score 3):

If Pjax reloads your entire page, then it means one of two reasons:

- Your Pjax contains an error (most likely this one and it could be some sort of `Exception` usually). To check whether you got one, in your JS file (or somewhere, where PJax ending event is taking place) write an additional event listener.

For example, if you have this event trigger:

```
$(document).on('pjax:end', function(e) {
    alert('Pjax has ended!');
});
```

Then you can also have something like this:

```
$(document).on('pjax:error', function(event, xhr) {
    alert('Pjax failed!');
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Now you can check if you `Pjax` contains an error. If you see first alert but not the second one, you don't have Pjax errors. If you get **both** alerts, your response contains an error and you can now check what do you get in console.

- Your Pjax's response contains core HTML tags (`<head>`, `<body>`).

This is not an error but browser does not understand if you're expecting to get a response without page refresh, therefore, attempts to reload completely. This might be harder to solve since I'm not quite sure how to prevent from getting core HTML tags. For an error you at least can see what's wrong. But, as I have said, it's most likely the first option here.

It is unlikely that you face another type of results. I strongly recommend to make sure you pass these two.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested, I have not any pjax errors. How I can solve second problem?

Comment: @hamed Check you response. What does console say about this?

Comment: The response is a complete html with head and body tags.

Comment: @hamed Well, as I have said, I'm not sure myself yet. Depends on your results. It is possible to splice but only works if you expect value from specific place (poor suggestion, though).

Comment: Could you explain me further? I want to prevent reloading the page after ajax request. Is it possible at all? This is working fine until 3 days ago, but all of my grids stop working suddenly!!! I don't know what part of project has effect in pjax functionally from 3 days ago. I really need to solve this critical problem. Thank you.

Comment: @hamed Did you check console? Do you your expected results in there (that with all html tags and texts)? Or is it some sort of not found message (without using exception)? If you see your results, then it might be like insufficient timeout length (but if it's 10000, then unlikely). Pjax has a lot of options, hard to tell without seeing all of them.

Comment: I checked it, the response is right, without any errors or exceptions, and also sort and filters applied correctly.

Comment: I checked my previous project in yii2. In that project, Pjax's ajax request returns just the page(without layout). In the other words, I see the ajax response start with `<title>` tag, not `html` tag. But in this case, I see entire page in the ajax response. I really don't know what are defferences between these two projects :(

Comment: Problems should be limited. Check your return. Maybe Controller now returns totally different thing comparing to previous project?

Comment: The controller has exactly same return.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120767/discussion-between-edvin-tenovimas-and-hamed).

Comment: Problem seems to be pjax timeout for most of the cases, try increasing it or setting it to false